# How to deal with strongly varying data sizes in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm wondering about the best practice in designing spark-jobs where the volume of data is not known in advance (or is strongly varying). In my case, the application should both handle initial loads and later on incremental data.

I wonder how I should set the number of partitions in my data (e.g. using `repartition` or setting parameters like  `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` in order to avoid OOM excpetion in the executors (giving fixed amount of allocated memory per executor). I could

1. define a very high number of partition to make sure that even on very high workloads, the job does not fail
2. Set number of partitions at runtime depending on the size of source-data
3. Introduce an iteration over independent chunks of data (i.e. looping)

In all option, I see issues:

1: I imagine this to be inefficient for small data sizes as taks get very small

2: Needs additional querys (e.g. `count`) and e.g. for setting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, `SparkContext` needs to be  restartet which I would like to avoid

3: Seems to contradict the spirit of Spark

So I wonder what the most efficient strategy is for strongly varying data volumes.

EDIT:
I was wrong about setting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, this can be set at runtime woutout restarting spark context

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not set a high number of partitions without knowing this is needed. You will absolutely kill the performance of your job.
2. Yes
3. As you said, don't loop!

As you mention, you introduce an extra step which is to count your data, which at first glance seems wrong. However, you shouldn't think of this as mis-spent computation. Usually, the time it takes to count your data is significantly less than the time it would take to do further processing if you partition the data badly. Think of the count operation as an investment, it's certainly worth it.

You do not need to set partitions through the config and restart Spark. Instead, do the following:

1. Note current number of partitions for RDD / Dataframe / Dataset
2. Count number of entries / rows in your data
3. Based on an estimate of average row size, compute the target number of partitions
4. If #targetPartitions << #actualPartitions Then coalesce
5. Else If #targetPartitions >> #actualPartitions Then repartition
6. Else #targetPartitions ~= #actualPartitions Then do nothing

The coalesce operation will re-partition your data without shuffling, and so is much more efficient when it is available.

Ideally you can estimate the number of rows your will generate, rather than count them. Also, you will need to think carefully about when it is appropriate to perform this operation. With a long RDD lineage you can kill performance, because you may inadvertently reduce the number of cores which can execute complex code, due to scala lazy execution. Look into checkpointing to mitigate this problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But this still leaves the issues on how to set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` at runtime, because for joining large table I need a higher value than for joining small tables, otherwise I will run out of memory. AFAIK during (shuffle-)joins, the initial number of partitions does not matter, or I'm I wrong?